# How can I show the coordinates in my beginner sketches?

Tags: processing

As I experiment with Processing (for loops and variables) I'm always trying to figure out which point relates to which iteration of my variable:

```
 for (i = 10; i <100; i +=5) {
   rect (i, i+10, 50, 50);
}
```

Is there someway for me to show the coordinates next to their points? Or is it possible to colour code iterations? Possibly making the first one red, then blue, etc.

Any pointing to resources, or examples very welcome.

Comment: Is that really and "if" not a "for" - is this javascript? C++... what? Add a language tag

Comment: Oops. I'll amend it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort of like that?

```
size(400,400);
colorMode(HSB);
for(int i = 10; i <255; i +=24) {
  int x = i;
  int y = i+10;
  fill(i,255,255);
  rect (x, y, 50, 50);
  fill(0);
  text(x + "," + y,x,y,100,100);
}
```

Comment: another option would be drawing some lines as the axes: `void drawAxes(int size){ pushStyle();stroke(255,0,0);line(0,0,size,0);stroke(0,255,0);line(0,0,0,size);popStyle();}` but Petros' option is simpler. Also the fill colour can be changed to reflect a change in position.